# Finding perfect numbers between 1-1000 only using loops and if statements in Java

Tags: java, loops, perfect-numbers

I know that this question has been asked many times before, but I haven't seen any using this method. Before any comments about this being homework, yes, it is, but I'm not looking for a complete answer, I'm only looking for a push in the right direction. Basically, my problem with this code is that it only outputs the number '0'. I was wondering where I went wrong.

```
public class Perfect {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int LIMIT = 1_000;
    int i;
    int x;
    int works = 0;

    for(i = 1; i <= LIMIT; i++) 
        if(works == i - 1) {
            System.out.print(works + " ");
        }
        for(x = 2; x <= i; x++)
            if(i % x == 0) {
                works = works + x;
            }
            else
                works = works;
}
```

}

Comment: Add missing `{ }` after the for loops. The first one only evaluates the `works == i - 1` condition. What you want to achive are nested loops.

Answer (score 3):

One thing that you're doing wrong is that you're not using `{}` for you for loops.

The way you've indented it is not the way it is being executed.

The way it's being executed is as follows.

```
for(i = 1; i <= LIMIT; i++) {
    if(works == i - 1) {
        System.out.print(works + " ");
    }
}

for(x = 2; x <= i; x++) {
   if(i % x == 0) {
      works = works + x; 
   }
   else {
      works = works;
   }
}
```

It's good practice to always use `{}` with loops and if statements to prevent this sort of error.

Comment: I wish I had more than one upvote to give this.

If you can use braces, always use braces, even if it's only one line of code inside the braces.  This ensures you don't make this mistake, and is pretty much required-style at most large software shops for that reason.

Comment: I've added the '{}', but I'm only getting '0' and '2' as output. Can someone give me a hint as to why that is?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that the loops aren't nested.

Change it to the following:

```
for(i = 1; i <= LIMIT; i++){ 
    if(works == i - 1) {
        System.out.print(works + " ");
    }
    for(x = 2; x <= i; x++) {
        if(i % x == 0) {
            works = works + x;
        } else {
            works = works;
        }
    }
}
```

When using a for loop without `{ }` only the next expression belongs to the for loop. This means that you have two independent loops in your code. The first one iterates from `1` to `LIMIT` and checks the condition `if(works == i - 1)`. This is the reason why it puts out only `0`.

The second loop just iterates from `2` to `LIMIT` and there will be no check if `works == i - 1`.

By the way: The assignment `works = works` in your else case does nothing so you can remove it.